# SSO login in ASP.NET MVC web application can not open Microsoft page for login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, single-sign-on

I am trying to add extra login with Microsoft to our project. I have created the app in Azure and did everything as the sample code that Azure provided for me, but when I press the login with Microsoft, it can not be redirected to Microsoft login page and it stays on the login page.
[azure screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kroc.png)
Here is my startup code:

```
public class Startup
{         
    string clientId = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];

    string redirectUri = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUri"];

    static string tenant = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tenant"];

    string authority = String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authority"], tenant);

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
       app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
       app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
       app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
      app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

      app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions { });

         app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
               // AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false // This is a simplification
                },
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
                }
            }
        );
    }

    private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context)
    {
        context.HandleResponse();
        context.Response.Redirect("/?errormessage=" + context.Exception.Message);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

I have tried the sample code from Azure .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUcXO.png)
and here is the part in web.config:

```
    <add key="ClientId" value=" our app client id " />
<add key="Tenant" value="organizations" />
<add key="Authority" 
 value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0" />
<add key="redirectUri" value="https://localhost:44300/"/>
```

Comment: Please share your configuration file `appsettings` by masking the values.

Comment: Have to set the `RedirectURI` correctly in the `AAD` ?

Comment: @Harshitha yes, it was the redirect uri that azure sample code provided me. that application sample works, but when I bring the configuration in our application, it does not work

Comment: Once set the Redirect URI in the registered application and check once.

Comment: Your `RedirectURI` must be in this format. `https://localhost:44300/signin-oidc`.

Comment: @Harshitha I tried it, no success, the same problem. but also in the sample code, they did not mention that the redirect uri should be with /signin-oidc , so I don't think it really related

Comment: `signin-oidc` is the default path for authenticating app.

Comment: Please share the screenshot of the redirect URI in the Azure Active Directory.

Comment: @Harshitha it does not work :(

Comment: Make sure your Redirect URI port no. is same as your local.[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLIi1.png) [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gC88G.png)

Answer (score 0):

The configurations which you have done and the middleware seems to be configured correctly.

The only difference I have found in your application settings is the `Redirect URI` of the localhost.

- From your screen shot it is clear that you have Configured Redirect URL  from the `Quickstart.
- By Default, same `Redirect URI` (**https://localhost:44368/**) will be added for all the applications which are configured from here.

[image]

- Click on the `Redirect URI's`.

[image]

- When you run your WebApp locally, the localhost port will be different.

[image]

- Updated with the correct `Port No.` in the `AAD` => `Authentication` => `Redirect URIs`.

[image]

- You can see now Iam able to login without any issues.

[image]

[image]

***My `Startup.Auth.cs`:***

```cs
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
using Owin;

namespace MVCSSO
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
        private static string aadInstance = EnsureTrailingSlash(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"]);
        private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
        private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];
        private static string authority = aadInstance + tenantId + "/v2.0";

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = authority,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,

                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                    {
                        SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                        {
                            string name = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("preferred_username").Value;
                            context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, name, string.Empty));
                            return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
                    }
                });
        }

        private static string EnsureTrailingSlash(string value)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                value = string.Empty;
            }

            if (!value.EndsWith("/", StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                return value + "/";
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

***Appsettings in `Web.config` file:***

```cs
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="ida:ClientId" value="******" />
    <add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/" />
    <add key="ida:Domain" value="****.onmicrosoft.com" />
    <add key="ida:TenantId" value="******" />
    <add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://localhost:44307/signin-oidc" />
  </appSettings>
```

- To make sure you have configured the `AppSettings` and Code correctly, download the Sample code from the `Quickstart` after setting the `RedirectURI`.
- All the settings with your correct values will be included in the code.Cross check with your Application and make changes accordingly.

[image]

Comment: I did these changes before, I used my own application URL for the redirect URL. these processes worked in one small sample code that I created and I can log in with Microsoft. the problem is that , in our application, I can not log in. it seems something is rewriting Microsoft login page in our app that I can not find it

Comment: Can you share your code repo?